# How to link OpenGL related libraries on mac using cmake?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, glfw, opengl-3

I am trying to complete a simple GLFW tutorial on mac using cmake, where I encounter a series of **undefined symbol** linking errors. I did my research regarding this issue and found no help. Below is my CMakeLists.txt.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(GL_Template)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(GLM REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED STATIC)

include_directories(${GLM_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(/usr/local/include)
include_directories(./include)
find_library(COCOA_LIBRARY Cocoa REQUIRED)
find_library(IOKIT_LIBRARY IOKit REQUIRED)
find_library(COREVID_LIBRARY CoreVideo REQUIRED)
message(${COCOA_LIBRARY})
message(${IOKIT_LIBRARY})
message(${COREVID_LIBRARY})


file(GLOB A_SOURCE ./src/*.cpp)

add_executable(Hello example/main.cpp ${A_SOURCE})
target_link_libraries(Hello ${GLEW_LIBRARY} ${GLFW3_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(Hello ${COCOA_LIBRARY} ${COREVID_LIBRARY} ${IOKIT_LIBRARY})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit")
```

Any help would be helpful.
Below is the error message

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glfwCreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwGetTime", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwInit", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwMakeContextCurrent", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwPollEvents", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwSetCursorPosCallback", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwSetInputMode", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwSetKeyCallback", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwSetScrollCallback", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwSetWindowShouldClose", referenced from:
      key_callback(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int) in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwSwapBuffers", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwTerminate", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwWindowHint", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwWindowShouldClose", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [Hello] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Hello.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I don't see a call which sets `GLFW3_LIBRARIES` variable; call to `pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)` sets `GLFW` prefixed variables. Also, unlike to `find_package` command, with `find_library` command *REQUIRED* option has no meaning. As for `-framework` linker flag, it is better to set it with [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/target_link_libraries.html) command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Obviously the GLFW3_LIBRARY is not defined and the defined variable should be GLFW_LIBRARY.